# Django searching listview with multiple queries and pagination

Tags: python, django, listview, search, pagination

I have this problem
https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/52vmyg/pagination_with_search/
but instead of 1 search term being passed to my pagination links I need to list multiple.

for example

```
<a class="page-link" href="?status={{ request.GET.status }}&page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
```

works fine but I need to put in multiple objects and scared the template code will become unreadable, is there any way I can access request.GET items with a generic for loop?

or perhaps a better way to code the pagination

Answer (score 0):

found it, using {{ request.get_full_path }} will get me the info I need into my template

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/